# how to Mock a fuction that call of Stored Procedure (python)

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, stored-procedures, mocking

I want to test function that call stored procedure. after recherche I found that we can mock (`patch`) database operations.

I have already tried to patch the connexion with the database.

i want to know how can I `patch` a call of function *funct2*( call `Stored Procedure`) so that I can give its output manually

for ex. the output of Stored procedure is :

```
data= ({'x': 13, 'y': 'san'})
```

this is how look like  my code

```
class db()
    def  __init__(host, user,password,dbname)
    def funct2()

 class A
    def func1(self):
        data = self.dbObj.funct2()
        # use this data to test something
         ....

dbObj=db(host, user,password, dbname)
```

I do not want to connect to any database during this tests,  want to give this output manually in my function_test(*func1*)

Comment: Can you add what you've tried so far please?

Comment: thanks for your response.i add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would accept a database (or some abstraction for one) as a parameter to the constructor. This way you can easily pass in a mock object. For example:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


class A(object):

    def __init__(self, db=None):
        self.db = db

    def func1(self):
        data = self.db.func2()
        return data


class ExampleMockingTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        mock_db = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_db.func2.return_value = {'x': 13, 'y': 'san'}

        # Pass in your mock to your object
        a = A(db=mock_db)

        # Do stuff with A...
        self.assertIn('x', a.func1())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

For details on mocking in Python, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer. i want to use this data to test something in func1 . func1 call func2(retrun data), and func1 use this data to test some excecution .  i think i must mock this line `data = self.dbObj.funct2()`  . i used the principe of your answer, but in test_func1 , i get error  **'my_class' object has no attribute 'dbObj' ** . Because i call `myclass.func1` in my test

Comment: thanks. I used patch , withour using class A (that you write in test) i just write :

**OB=A(mock_D)**
 **Actual =OB.func1()**
 **Expected = ....**